# Problema com "Double" na minha calculadora que eu fiz em linguagem "C"

Tags: c

Estava fazendo uma calculadora simples em "C" só para exercitar  lógica, o que eu aprendi e por diversão, mas tive problemas , já que eu gostaria de transforma-la e uma calculadora cientifica,eu precisaria de mais memória do que o `Float` pode usar, então tentei usar o `Double`, que deu um erro bizarro, de dar um valor aleatório muito grande quando eu faço `(10+10)` por exemplo. Código a baixo usando o "Float".

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
int main(){
//VAR
int conti=0;    
float numero1;
float numero2;
float resultado;
char equacao;
int potencia;
int A;
float soma (float numero1,float numero2,float resultado,int primeiravez);
float subtracao (float numero1,float numero2,float resultado,int primeiravez);
float multiplicacao (float numero1,float numero2,float resultado,int primeiravez);
float divisao (float numero1,float numero2,float resultado,int primeiravez);
float porcentagem (float numero1,float numero2,float resultado,int primeiravez);
float raiz(float numero1,float resultado,int primeiravez);
//FIM VAR
//EXPLICAÇÃO
printf("Esse programa faz tudo que uma calculadora simples faz,ou seja.\n");
printf("Soma(+)\nSubtracao(-)\nDivisao(/)\nMultiplicacao(*)\nRaiz(#)\nPorcentagem(%%)\n");
printf("Comece:\n");
//INICIO CÓDIGOS
A=1;
scanf ("%f", &numero2);
scanf ("%s", &equacao);
//INICIO EQUAÇÃO
do{
if(equacao=='+' or equacao=='-' or equacao=='*' or equacao=='=' or equacao=='/'
or equacao=='%' or equacao=='#' ){
//SE SOMA   
if(equacao=='+'){
    numero1=numero2;
scanf("%f",&numero2);   
resultado=soma(numero1,numero2,resultado,A);
scanf("%s",&equacao);
A=0;
}
//SE SUBTRAÇÃO
if(equacao=='-'){
    numero1=numero2;
scanf("%f",&numero2);   
resultado=subtracao(numero1,numero2,resultado,A);
scanf("%s",&equacao);
A=0;    
}
//SE MULTIPLICAÇÃO
if(equacao=='*'){
numero1=numero2;
scanf("%f",&numero2);   
resultado=multiplicacao(numero1,numero2,resultado,A);
scanf("%s",&equacao);
A=0;        
}
//SE DIVISÃO
if(equacao=='/'){
numero1=numero2;
scanf("%f",&numero2);   
resultado=divisao(numero1,numero2,resultado,A);
scanf("%s",&equacao);
A=0;        
}
//SE PORCENTAGEM
if(equacao=='%'){
    numero1=numero2;
scanf("%f",&numero2);
    resultado = porcentagem (numero1,numero2,resultado,A);
    scanf("%s",&equacao);
    A=0;
}
//SE RAIZ
if(equacao=='#'){
    numero1=numero2;
    resultado = raiz (numero1,resultado,A);
    scanf("%s",&equacao);
    A=0;
}
//MOSTRANDO RESULTADO
if(equacao=='='){
    printf("%f \n",resultado);
    conti=1;
}
}
else{
    printf("VALOR INVALIDO \n");
    conti=1;
}
}while(conti==0);
system("PAUSE");
return 0;   

}

//FUNÇÕES
float soma (float numero1,float numero2,float resultado,int primeiravez){
    if(primeiravez==1){
    resultado=numero1+numero2;
    }else{
resultado=numero2+resultado;    
}
return resultado;
}
float subtracao (float numero1,float numero2,float resultado,int primeiravez){
    if(primeiravez==1){
    resultado=numero1-numero2;
}else{
resultado=resultado-numero2;    
}
return resultado;
}
float multiplicacao (float numero1,float numero2,float resultado,int primeiravez){
    if(primeiravez==1){
    resultado=numero1*numero2;
}else{
resultado=resultado*numero2;
}
return resultado;
}
float divisao (float numero1,float numero2,float resultado,int primeiravez){
if(primeiravez==1){
resultado=numero1/numero2;
}else{
resultado=resultado/numero2;
}
return resultado;
}
float porcentagem (float numero1,float numero2,float resultado,int primeiravez){
    if(primeiravez==1){
resultado=numero1*(numero2/100);
}else{
resultado=resultado/(numero2/100);
}
return resultado;
}
float raiz(float numero1,float resultado,int primeiravez){
if(primeiravez==1){
resultado= sqrt(numero1);
}else{
resultado= sqrt(resultado);
}
return resultado;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Alguns pontos para te ajudar

1. usa sempre `double` para variáveis ou funcoes de vírgula flutuante
2. é costume por-se os protótipos das funções fora da função `main()`
3. O conversor para input de valores de tipo `double` é `"%lf"`. Ao mudares as variáveis para `double`, muda também os `scanf()`s
4. `scanf ("%s", &equacao);` está **MUITO** mal! A variavel `equacao` é de tipo `char`, mas o conversor `"%s"` é usado para strings. Ou usas o conversor `"%c"` ou mudas o tipo da variável (mas atenção aos espaços em branco)
5. Os operadors lógicos `and` e `or` só estão disponíveis depois de fazeres `#include <iso646.h>`
6. **melhora a indentação do teu código**

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda :)